# Can't fit react-player into div

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using react-player from npm and want it to fit in a div that is centered in the middle of screen and to be responsive of course. Whatever I try, the player spreads fully on-screen and disappears when switching to a mobile view. Can anyone help me, please?

This is how a parent component looks like:

```
const Film = () => {
return (
    <div className="film__container">
        <div className="film__box">
            <Reactplayer />
        </div>
    </div>
 )
}
```

This is a component with player:

```
const Reactplayer = () => {
return (
    <div className='player-wrapper'>
        <ReactPlayer
        className='react-player'
        url={video}
        width='100%'
        height='100%'
        controls={true}
        />
    </div>
 )
}
```

and css (sass):

```
.film__container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.film__box {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}

.player-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   padding-top: 56.25% 
}

.react-player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Second component and classes that refers to it are exactly the same as in react-player npm docs.

This is how it look in gh-pages: [pietrzi.github.io/strona-piotrb/#/film](https://pietrzi.github.io/strona-piotrb/#/film)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `.react-player` contains a `video` element which styling causes your problems. The styling places the video for example `right: -400px`

[image]

Add this CSS to your code (reset the video styling):

```
.react-player video {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: none;
}
```